# posting high score on facebook using graph api

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Edit: 10-9-10
I think the app is crashing when the JSON library tries to parse the

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d weeks",[components week]];
```

How would i format it so that JSON can parse it?

Here's the JSON code line

```
NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
        NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              kAppId, @"api_key",
                               @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                               actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                              attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                               nil];
```

Can anyone point me to a tutorial on how to do this? I can easily post the static text in the code block below but i can't integrate an `NSString` with dynamic data, it doesn't show up on the Fb post attachment section.

```
 NSDictionary *attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"Testing", @"name",
                         @"testing2", @"caption",
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d weeks",[components week]], @"description"//Xcode says components undeclared 

//highscore, @"description", //here's the problem, highscore is the NSString variable.
                          @"http://testing.com/", @"href", nil];
```

Update: 
the problem is the string i'm using is from a time interval of the difference of 2 weeks and the out put is `[components week]` and then xcode tells me components is an undeclared variable

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d weeks",[components week]]
```

here's the whole date code block that i get the string above from:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"20100716";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr]; 
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
fromDate:startDate
toDate:endDate options:0];

NSInteger weeks = [components week];
NSInteger days = [components day];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try stringWithFormat `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", highscore];` instead of highscore